# Cocoa app crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS, but only on Mac OS X 10.6.6

Tags: cocoa, osx-snow-leopard, exc-bad-access

I received a couple of crash reports from users running Mac OS X 10.6.6. My app crashes with the error below:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000060443800
Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: release


Thread 0 Crashed:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libobjc.A.dylib                0x97d98edb objc_msgSend + 27
1   com.apple.LaunchServices       0x9038dc62 __LSSharedFileListItemDeallocate + 126
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x9489d101 _CFRelease + 353
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x948c75b2 __CFArrayReleaseValues + 210
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation       0x9489d101 _CFRelease + 353
5   ...myapp.AppName 0x00005d67 +[ABTools isLoginItem] + 1597
```

The code that breaks is trying to determine if the application has installed a login item. The 3rd to last line releasing the array fails (on 10.6.6, works on 10.5.8).

Can anybody see why that would happen? I looked at that code for way too long and I don't see it.

Thanks!
Mark

```
+ (BOOL) isLoginItem {

    BOOL isLoginItem = NO;

    UInt32 seedValue;

    NSString *appName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.app", [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"CFBundleName"]];
    NSString *appPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];

    LSSharedFileListRef loginItems = LSSharedFileListCreate(NULL,kLSSharedFileListSessionLoginItems,NULL);
    if (!loginItems) {
        return isLoginItem;
    }
    CFURLRef url = (CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:appPath];

    NSArray *loginItemsArray = (NSArray *)LSSharedFileListCopySnapshot(loginItems, &seedValue);

    if (!loginItemsArray) {
        return isLoginItem;
    }
    for (id item in loginItemsArray)
    {  
        if (LSSharedFileListItemResolve((LSSharedFileListItemRef)item,0,(CFURLRef*)&url,NULL) == noErr
            && [[(NSURL *)url path] isEqualToString:appPath]) {

            isLoginItem = YES;
        }
        if (url) CFRelease(url);
    }

    if (loginItemsArray) [loginItemsArray release]; // THIS FAILS ON Mac OS X 10.6.6
    if (loginItems) CFRelease(loginItems);

    return isLoginItem;
}
```

Comment: I believe you have a memory management mistake. Why are you releasing `url` (`if (url) CFRelease(url)`)? You didn't get it from a `new`, `alloc`, or `copy`, nor did you retain it.

Comment: The url is allocated in LSSharedFileListItemResolve. One thing I thought about was that I'm calling release instead of CFRelease for the array. Maybe that's the problem...

Comment: @kevingessner caller is responsible for releasing output url of `LSSharedFileListItemResolve` see `LSSharedFileList.h`.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Those C APIs can be tricky.

Comment: Note that you are failing to release the shared file list object when `LSSharedFileListCopySnapshot` returns `NULL`.

Comment: As a workaround for the crash, you might try not releasing the URLs in the loop, and only releasing the array at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the problem that you are having, but I have used this code for my app and it is working perfectly [Enabling launch on startup](http://www.bdunagan.com/2010/09/25/cocoa-tip-enabling-launch-on-startup/)

Answer (score 2):

In general, changes in .x.y releases should not cause previously working apps to crash. I suggest you file a bug at bugreport.apple.com.

Comment: I disagree. It's perfectly possible to have a program that's doing something incorrectly (buggy) but does not crash. (For example, relying on the contents of uninitialized memory). Just because an OS upgrade causes the latent bug to become visible does not mean that the crash is the OS's fault.

Comment: It's really not a matter of "fault" (I've rarely found fault to be a useful concept in engineering). Applications do stuff wrong all the time, and sometimes those will break in .x updates. .x.y updates are supposed to be safe though, even if that requires working around broken apps. That way users won't be hesitant to apply them, which would be bad since they often contain security fixes.